# is there a TableDisplayFor HTML helper in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

ASP.NET/MVC, I occasionally made use of Stephen Muecke's MVC Html table helper: [MVC Html Table Helper](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774228/MVC-Html-Table-Helper-Part-Display-Tables)

This provides a number of HTML helpers, the center one is `@Html.TableDisplayFor()`.

In a Razor page, if my view model contained a list of something, I could display the list in a table very simply:

```
@if (Model.MySomethings != null && Model.MySomethings.Count > 0)
{
    @Html.TableDisplayFor(m => m.MySomethings)
}
```

It would create a table with a row for every something in the list, with a column for every property in the something type.

And it would do it dynamically, without my having to make changes just because the underlying model type had changed.

It's very convenient, for certain types of problems.

But it was built for ASP.NET/MVC, on the full/classic .NET Framework.

Is there anything similar for ASP.NET Core on .NET 5.0?

Comment: `Sandtrap` was implemented for the .net framework MVC4 at the time. If it is to be used in .Net 5, it needs to be rewritten according to the logic again.